# First PDF download always redirects to the admin dashboard

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, pdf, permissions

The first time you try and download a PDF from the admin area after logging in (for example "Print" when viewing an order invoice) you get redirected to the administrators dashboard.

The next time you try it, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

After much digging, and process of elimination, I found that the user must have "Show Toolbar" permission enabled. I don't know why this affects it, but for some reason it does!

[image]